# Can't get one document from flutter cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get one document by user id from firebase cloud firestore using flutter.
I tried firstly to fetch the data then added a condition to it, but i'm not able to display the data or even print it in the console!

Here is what i've tried so far:

database.dart:

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot?> getFileByUser(String userId) async {  
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance  
        .collection('cartesPro') 
        .where('cartUserId', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        print(element.id);  
      });   
    });
  }
```

ui page:

```
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  showFile() {
    final files = DatabaseMethods().getFileByUser(user!.uid);
    print(files);
  }
```

and then made the call in a button so I can print the result only! it's returning the documents of the actual user, but I couldn't map the result in order to get the latest in timestamp order!
I appreciate any kind of help, thanks in advance!

Comment: why you have not simply not added ``FirebaseFirestore.instance      .collection('cartesPro').orderBy('timestamp')``` to your query ?

Comment: tried that now and it's asking me to create an index for the query, waiting for the build of the index..

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it's now returning me a JsonQuerySnapshot object, i'll see how to extract my data from it!

Comment: doc.data() (document properties) and doc.id

Comment: I tried the following: 
showFile() {

    final files = DatabaseMethods().getFileByUser(user!.uid);

    files.then((value) {

      print(value.docs.length);

    });

  } but it's always returning 0, although I added 2 new files to the db!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the most recent document for the user, you should order on the field that has the timestamp and the limit to a single result:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance  
    .collection('cartesPro') 
    .where('cartUserId', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
    .limit(1)
    .get()
```

See the Firestore documentation on [ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) for more on this.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it's now returning me a JsonQuerySnapshot object, i'll see how to extract my data from it!